# Can you delete a specific file before building in Visual Studio 2019/2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, msbuild

The project I am working on creates a cache file the first time it is built and ran, but if you make a code change and then re-run the project the file doesn't replace the cache and will instead run the old version of the code. To fix this you have to manually delete the file every time, but I was wondering if there is a way to get Visual Studio to delete that file any time it has to build/rebuild new code?

I am using a regular VS solution generated by CMake.

Comment: You can, but wouldn't it be better for your program to detect that the cache file is stale and needs to be recreated?

Comment: I agree that it would be better, but unfortunately that is not my area to change and the person who would be responsible for changing that is inundated with high priority work for the foreseeable future. But if you can do it I will happily take an explanation of how it is done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea would be use Visual Studio Build Events.
Read the doc about how to personalize Build Events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/ide/specifying-custom-build-events-in-visual-studio?).
Using custom Build events you can run command before or after a compiling process.

Comment: This worked a treat, although it took me a while to realise that I had to use CMD calls and not PowerShell calls. Thanks 